# Get a enum with rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums

On Ror 7.0, with postgres, I have a model created with the following migration:

```
create_enum :examen_cpf, ["attente formation", "attente qcm", "attente evaluations", "terminé"]
create_table :examen_cpfs do |t|
  t.enum :state, enum_type: :examen_cpf, default: "attente formation", null: false
end
```

in a model I want to list the enum.
How can I get it ?
I try:

- ExamenCpf.examen_cpf_enum
- ExamenCpf.examen_cpf
  ....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a table, declass the enum in the class - the field in the table will just be an integer field